# al insertar un slider de imagenes dentro de un fragment me da un error en java

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hola soy nuevo en la plataforma y programando también, tengo el siguiente problema al insertar un slider dentro de un activity todo bien, pero cuando este codigo lo llevo a una fragment me da el siguiente error (incompatible type: Fragment cannot be converted to context) dejo el código debajo, saludos.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

        int images[]={R.drawable.agente, R.drawable.a_discovery, R.drawable.nueveonce};
        v_flipper=view.findViewById(R.id.v_flipper);
        for(int image:images){
            flipperimages(image);
        }

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
   
    private  void  flipperimages(int image){
        ImageView imageView =new ImageView(this);  //error en los this
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);
        v_flipper.addView(imageView);
        v_flipper.setFlipInterval(7000);
        v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);
        v_flipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);  //error en los this
        v_flipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);  //error en los this
    }
```

Comment: Agrega los errores

Comment: El problema es el contexto que estas usando, revisa mi respuesta, usa https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getActivity() en tu Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias a David Estrada por su colaboración, al final resolví el error sustituyendo los `this` por el método `getContext()` de la clase fragment y todo ok.

Answer (score 1):

Si te encuentras en un  `Fragment` lo ideal es usar el contexto de la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, por lo tanto si usas aquí `this` es incorrecto:

```
 ImageView imageView =new ImageView(this);  //error en los this
```

**usa el contexto la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, en este caso usa [**getActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getActivity())** :

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

Answer (score -1):

esto se debe a que estas retornando

```
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

Reemplazalo por

```
return view;
```

Crea tu variable -

```
private static MainActivity myContext
```

Después asignas valor mediante:

```
public MainActivity() { myContext = this; }
```

Y creas la funcion para llamarla desde el fragment

```
public static MainActivity getInstance() { return myContext; }
```

Ahora reemplaza los this asi:

```
ImageView imageView =new ImageView(getInstance());  //error en los this
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);
        v_flipper.addView(imageView);
        v_flipper.setFlipInterval(7000);
        v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);
        v_flipper.setInAnimation(getInstance(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);  
        v_flipper.setOutAnimation(getInstance(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola David, gracias por responder cambie lo que me sugeriste pero me sigue dando el mismo error, este es el error (incompatible type: Fragment cannot be converted to context) y me señala los (this) Saludos.

Comment: Ok, esto sucede porque un fragment no genera un contexto como tal.
Prueba creando un contexto en tu Mainactivity declarando una variable asi:
private static MainActivity myContext;   Despues cras un constructor para asignarle valor de esta forma: 
public MainActivity() {
        myContext =  this;
    }
Y despues cras una funcion para pasar el contexto cuando lo necesites asi: 
public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return myContext;
    }

Ahora solo remplazas tus this por getInstance() y esto solucionaria tu problema